# Need to sum next 16 columns after the last column containing a 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

I would want, starting from the seventeenth column, to sum the numbers till the last 1 (16 columns). However, for the second 1, and everything after, I don't want there to be any summation, as it doesn't meet the condition of having a zero before it. I was using `SUMIF`, but when I try to extend it across my sheet, it continues to sumif eg - `SUMIF(A1:A16, "=0", A17:A33)`, I'll still get a non-zero value for my second 1.

Comment: I have read this three times and am confused.  What should the answer be?

Comment: Is it always 16 columns that you want to add? It might be a good idea to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1454199/edit) to include the expected output

Comment: re: *for the second 1, and everything after, I don't want there to be any summation, as it doesn't meet the condition of having a zero before it.* If the second 1 **did** have a zero before it then the zero you were referring to to get the first 1 wouldn't be *the last column containing a 0* would it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this is what you want, but here it goes:

In `B2`, use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(SUM($A1:A1)=0,B1>0),SUM(B1:Q1),"")
```

and populate right

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will find the first in the range that is not `0` and then sum the next 16 columns.

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:AH1,MATCH(0,A1:AH1)+1):INDEX(A1:AH1,MIN(MATCH(0,A1:AH1)+16,COLUMNS(A1:AH1))))
```

`MATCH(0,A1:AH1)` returns the relative column number where the current cell is `0` and the next is greater than `0`.  we add one to the beginning and 17 to the end the range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest few tricky methods using `SUMIF` & `SUMPRODUCT` functions:*

**How it works:**

- Both method needs Helper values, `1` to `34` in Row `1`(check screen shot).

[image]

- Formula in Cell `AV3:`

  ```
  =SUMIFS(N2:AU2,N1:AU1,">=17",N1:AU1,"<=32")
  ```
- Enter this Formula in Cell `AV4:`

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(N2:AU2,{17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32}))
  ```

---

*If you are dealing with huge Data set then you may use this Formula.*

```
=SUM(INDEX(N2:AU2,0,COLUMNS(N2:AU2)-(L$6-3)):INDEX(N2:AU2,0,COLUMNS(N2:AU2)))
```

- Cell `L6` carries count of `1s`, better use this Formula in cell `L6`.

  `=COUNTIF(N2:AU2,1)`
- You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.